# MySQL syntax error Match() Against() column alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm working through some examples of full text searching with MySQL and I'm getting a syntax error when trying to alias a generated column using MATCH() and AGAINST

```sh
$ cat <<- EOF | mysql -u root -ppassword -h 127.0.0.1 -v --table crashcourse | pbcopy
SELECT note_text,
       Match(note_text) Against('rabbit') AS rank
FROM productnotes;
EOF
--------------
SELECT note_text,
       Match(note_text) Against('rabbit') AS rank
FROM productnotes
--------------

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank
FROM productnotes' at line 2
```

However, not trying to alias it works just fine:

```sh
$ cat <<- EOF | mysql -u root -ppassword -h 127.0.0.1 -v --table crashcourse | pbcopy
SELECT note_text,
       Match(note_text) Against('rabbit')
FROM productnotes;
EOF
--------------
SELECT note_text,
       Match(note_text) Against('rabbit')
FROM productnotes
--------------

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| note_text                                                                                                                                                 | Match(note_text) Against('rabbit') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Customer complaint:
Sticks not individually wrapped, too easy to mistakenly detonate all at once.
Recommend individual wrapping.                          |                                  0 |
| Can shipped full, refills not available.
Need to order new can if refill needed.                                                                          |                                  0 |
| Safe is combination locked, combination not provided with safe.
This is rarely a problem as safes are typically blown up or dropped by customers.         |                                  0 |
| Quantity varies, sold by the sack load.
All guaranteed to be bright and orange, and suitable for use as rabbit bait.                                      |                 1.5905543565750122 |
| Included fuses are short and have been known to detonate too quickly for some customers.
Longer fuses are available (item FU1) and should be recommended. |                                  0 |
| Matches not included, recommend purchase of matches or detonator (item DTNTR).                                                                            |                                  0 |
| Please note that no returns will be accepted if safe opened using explosives.                                                                             |                                  0 |
| Multiple customer returns, anvils failing to drop fast enough or falling backwards on purchaser. Recommend that customer considers using heavier anvils.  |                                  0 |
| Item is extremely heavy. Designed for dropping, not recommended for use with slings, ropes, pulleys, or tightropes.                                       |                                  0 |
| Customer complaint: rabbit has been able to detect trap, food apparently less effective now.                                                              |                 1.6408053636550903 |
| Shipped unassembled, requires common tools (including oversized hammer).                                                                                  |                                  0 |
| Customer complaint:
Circular hole in safe floor can apparently be easily cut with handsaw.                                                                |                                  0 |
| Customer complaint:
Not heavy enough to generate flying stars around head of victim. If being purchased for dropping, recommend ANV02 or ANV03 instead.   |                                  0 |
| Call from individual trapped in safe plummeting to the ground, suggests an escape hatch be added.
Comment forwarded to vendor.                            |                                  0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Am I missing something really basic?

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.16 for macos10.14 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Comment: `rank` is reserved word.

Comment: `RANK` is a reserved word.

Comment: *facepalm*, thanks!